# calling kernel32.dll function without including windows.h

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, shellcode

if kernel32.dll is guaranteed to loaded into a process virtual memory,why couldn't i call function such as Sleep without including windows.h?
the below is an excerpt quoting from vividmachine.com

> 5. So, what about windows? How do I find the addresses of my needed DLL functions? Don't these addresses change with every service pack upgrade?
>
> There are multitudes of ways to find the addresses of the functions that you need to use in your shellcode. There are two methods for addressing functions; you can find the desired function at runtime or use hard coded addresses. This tutorial will mostly discuss the hard coded method. The only DLL that is guaranteed to be mapped into the shellcode's address space is kernel32.dll. This DLL will hold LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress, the two functions needed to obtain any functions address that can be mapped into the exploits process space. There is a problem with this method though, the address offsets will change with every new release of Windows (service packs, patches etc.). So, if you use this method your shellcode will ONLY work for a specific version of Windows. Further dynamic addressing will be referenced at the end of the paper in the Further Reading section.

Comment: Don't indent paragraphs. Stackoverflow treats them as code. In the above case, make sure every paragraph you quote is prefixed with '>'.

Comment: And why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article you quoted focuses on getting the address of the function. You still need the function prototype of the function (which doesn't change across versions), in order to generate the code for calling the function - with appropriate handling of input and output arguments, register values, and stack.

The `windows.h` header provides the *function prototype* that you wish to call to the C/C++ compiler, so that the code for calling the function (the passing of arguments via register or stack, and getting the function's return value) can be generated.

After knowing the function prototype by reading `windows.h`, a skillful assembly programmer may also be able to write the assembly code to call the `Sleep` function. Together with the function's address, these are all you need to make the function call.

Answer (score 2):

With some black magic you can ;).  there have been many custom implementations of `GetProcAddress`, which would allow you to get away with not needing `windows.h`, this however isn't be all and end all and could probably end up with problems due to internal windows changes. Another method is using toolhlp to enumerate the modules in the process to get kernel.dll's base, then spelunks its PE for the EAT and grab the address of `GetProcAddress`.  from there you just need function pointer prototypes to call the addresses correctly(and any structure defs needed), which isn't too hard meerly labour intensive(if you have many functions), infact under windows xp this is required to disable DEP due to service pack differencing, ofc you need `windows.h` as a reference to get this, you just don't need to include it.

Comment: Hi Necrolis, could you lead me to one of the implementations of `GetProcAddress()` that do not use `Windows,h`.

Comment: @NabeelOmer: something like this should work just fine: http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/38615-getprocaddress-replacement/ (note: you will need to import the PE structs locally, but that is trivial)

Comment: Hi, I'm back :), I have added all the structs, typedefs and things to a header file, but i am having trouble with `strcmp()`, `strdup()`, and `strchr()` functions. Their definitions and declarations apparently are in the `Windows.h` file, but aren't they supposed to be in the C++ Standard Library (`stdlib.h`)?

Comment: @NabeelOmer: those (and many other functions) are provided by the runtime (normally msvcrt.dll under Windows); however, many compilers also implement them as intrinstics which can cause issues. Also, `stdlib.h`/`cstdlib` doesn't always include everything from the standard library: eg `strcmp` is from `cstring`/`string.h`

Comment: Yet again, I am back :) this time, I am having trouble with structs like `HINSTANCE` and `HMODULE`. What I have done is: `#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__{int unused;}; typedef struct name##__ *name` as it is in the windows.h file. Then I wrote `DECLARE_HANDLE(HINSTANCE);`. But the compiler (VS 2013) is giving me a error: `error C2011: HINSTANCE__ : struct type redefinition`

Comment: Which leads me to believe that some where in the `string` header there is a statement saying `#include windef.h`. How do I go around this?

Comment: @NabeelOmer: seeing as you are already do some rather brittle stuff here, you might as well define them as `void*`/`uintptr_t`.

Comment: Could you define _brittle?_

Comment: Another request: _Can I have your email address?_ This discussion is a little off topic here...

Answer (score 2):

You'd still need to declare the function in order to call it, and you'd need to link with kernel32.lib. The header file isn't anything magic, it's basically just a lot of function declarations.

Answer (score -2):

I can do it with 1 line of assembly and then some helper functions to walk the PEB
file by hard coding the correct offsets to different members.

You'll have to start here:

```
static void* 
JMIM_ASM_GetBaseAddr_PEB_x64()
{
    void* base_address = 0;
    unsigned long long var_out = 0;

    __asm__(
        " movq %%gs:0x60, %[sym_out]  ; \n\t"
        :[sym_out] "=r"  (var_out) //:OUTPUTS
    );

    //: printf("[var_out]:%d\n", (int)var_out);

    base_address=(void*)var_out;
    return( base_address );
}
```

Then use windbg on an executable file to inspect the data structures on your machine.
A lot of the values you'll be needing are hard to find and only really documented by random hackers. You'll find yourself on a lot of malware writing sites digging for answers.

```
dt nt!_PEB -r @$peb
```

Was pretty useful in windbg to get information on the PEB file.

There is a full working implementation of this in my game engine.
Just look in: /DEP/PEB2020  for the code.

https://github.com/KanjiCoder/AAC2020

I don't include <windows.h> in my game engine. Yet I use "GetProcAddress"
and "LoadLibraryA". Might be in-advisable to do this. But my thought was the more
moving parts, the more that can go wrong. So figured I'd take the "#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN" to it's absurd conclusion and not include <windows.h> at all.